# $\ker A \subset \ker A^2$? or backwards? $Im~ A \subset Im~ A^2$? or backwards?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, elementary-set-theory

Be $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Which of the following statements are true?

(i) $\ker A \subset \ker A^2 ~~ \forall A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

(ii) $\ker A \supset \ker A^2 ~~ \forall A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

(iii) $Im~ A \subset Im~ A^2 ~~ \forall A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

(iv) $Im~ A \supset Im~ A^2 ~~ \forall A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

My ideas so far:

(i) Is true,  $Ax=0 \Rightarrow A^2x=0$ by multiplying $A$

(ii) Is also true, $A^2x=0\Rightarrow Ax=0$ by multiplying $A^{-1}$

Is my solution so far correct? How to go on with $Im$?

Comment: Remember that not every matrix is inveritble, so $(ii)$ does not always holds.

Comment: Your (1) is correct, your (ii) is not as it assumes $\;A\;$ is invertible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct only for $i.$ and for $ii.$  $A$ may be singular! Of course if $A$ is invertible then $\ker A=\{0\}=\ker A^2$.

For the image we have $\operatorname{im}(A^2)\subset  \operatorname{im}(A)$: in fact if $y=A^2x\in \operatorname{im}(A^2)$ the $z=Ax\in \operatorname{im}(A)$.

To prove that the inclusion is strict in general in the two cases consider
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$Ax=0\implies A^2x=A(Ax)=A(0)=0$$

$$x=A^2y\;,\;\;Ay=z\implies x=Az=A(Ay)$$